# SQL join on attribute value contained in another field

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, concatenation

I would like to perform a join on attr_1 and attr_2 when:

- attr_1 = attr_2
- attr_1 is contained in attr_2

A good match is performed if attr_1 is one of the value of attr_2 separated by '/' .

| attr_1 | attr_2 |
| --- | --- |
| SOR:562 | ACCU:5698A/SOR:22/SOR:562 |
| SOR:120 | SOR:120/SOR:125 |
| SOR:89 | SOR:1001/ACCU:569/SOR:56239/SOR:89 |

But I don't want those matches as SOR:89 and SOR:899912 because it's not the same value (89 != 899912)

| attr_1 | attr_2 |
| --- | --- |
| SOR:89 | SOR:899912 |

How could I avoid wrong matches? (I tried this but it doesnt work:

`on t.attr_1 LIKE CONCAT('%',s.attr_2,'%')`)

Comment: What output are you trying to get from this?

Comment: I couldn't understand the role of separator character. How it's going to influence result?

Comment: The correct solution is to fix your broken database design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the second attribute to an array:

```
select *
from first_table t1
  join second_table t2 on t1.attr1 = any(string_to_array(t2.attr2, '/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
on t.attr_1 LIKE CONCAT('%',s.attr_2,'%')
```

I think what you are trying to get is

```
on t.attr_2 LIKE CONCAT('%',s.attr_1,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be:

```
ON CONCAT('/', attr_2, '/') LIKE CONCAT('%/', attr_1, '/%')
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=17d45f8eca9709f4eb94058df8ee9853).